# Как поменять элементы и тип данных np array по условию?

Tags: python, numpy

Как заполнить числовой массив стринговыми значениями по условию : "s", если значения меньше 3, "m", если значения в промежутке [3, 7],
"l", если значения больше 8?

```
my = np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 4, 2))
array([[[3, 3],
        [2, 1],
        [9, 2],
        [2, 5]],

       [[6, 9],
        [1, 4],
        [7, 4],
        [5, 1]],

       [[4, 4],
        [4, 4],
        [1, 8],
        [8, 2]]])
```

Пробую так например

```
my_array[((my_array>=3) & (my_array>=7)), dtype = 'string'] = 'm'
```

Безрезультатно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как-то так, может быть?:

```
import numpy as np

sizes = np.array(['s']*3  + ['m']*4 +['l']*3)
# ^^ это список, в котором задаются ключи по количеству элементов в интервалах, то есть
# от 0 до 3 (0,1,2) - 3 элемента, поэтому ['s']*3 , и т. д.

my = np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 4, 2))
print(my)

[[[5 7]
  [9 6]
  [9 1]
  [6 2]]

 [[2 9]
  [3 3]
  [8 9]
  [3 6]]

 [[2 1]
  [6 7]
  [2 4]
  [6 5]]]

print(sizes[my])

[[['m' 'l']
  ['l' 'm']
  ['l' 's']
  ['m' 's']]

 [['s' 'l']
  ['m' 'm']
  ['l' 'l']
  ['m' 'm']]

 [['s' 's']
  ['m' 'l']
  ['s' 'm']
  ['m' 'm']]]
```

Update - для другого диапазона:

```
import numpy as np
sizes = np.array(['s']*19  + ['m']*10 +['l']*8)

my = np.random.randint(15, 37, (2, 3, 4))
print(my)
print(sizes[my])

[[[19 20 25 19]
  [19 25 24 30]
  [31 34 19 23]]

 [[35 36 31 28]
  [17 19 22 36]
  [18 30 16 27]]]
[[['m' 'm' 'm' 'm']
  ['m' 'm' 'm' 'l']
  ['l' 'l' 'm' 'm']]

 [['l' 'l' 'l' 'm']
  ['s' 'm' 'm' 'l']
  ['s' 'l' 's' 'm']]]
```

Логика такова: у вас диапазон 0-19 включительно - small, 20-29 включительно - medium, 30 и выше - large. максимальное значение, которое вы задали в np.random.randint - 37. Отсюда получается маска:

```
sizes = np.array(['s']*19  + ['m']*10 +['l']*8)
#      от 0 до 19 (19) ^^ 
#                 от 20 до 29 (10) ^^
#                            от 30 до 38 (8) ^^
```

Comment: Если взять такой интервал, то у меня не работает

Comment: my = np.random.randint(15, 37, (2, 3, 4))

Comment: sizes = np.array(['small']*20  + ['medium']*30 + ['large']*37) здесь выводит только small и medium корректно, а large не видит

Comment: "small", если значения меньше 20
* "medium", если значения в промежутке [20, 30]
* "large", если значения больше 30

Comment: по количеству элементов тоже не работает

Comment: То есть по количеству элементов если беру sizes = np.array(['small']*5  + ['medium']*11 + ['large']*7) выводит ошибку index 26 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 23

Comment: Может повторно другой вопрос задать, ведь в конкретном ответе на конкретный вопрос ответ рабочий дан?

Comment: Повторно не надо. вы неверно понимаете логику ответа моего. какие интервалы у вас при `np.random.randint(15, 37, (2, 3, 4))`? с какого по какой small, medium, large?

Comment: "small", если значения меньше 20 * "medium", если значения в промежутке [20, 30] * "large", если значения больше 30

Comment: @svil обновил ответ. массив sizes должен быть такого же размера, как и максимальное значение в вашем random.randint. Выведите для себя sizes на печать, поймете логику работы сразу.

Comment: Спасибо, вникаю.